# MongoDB Update Statement Set Value From Other Collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, updates, conditional-statements

I have a background in SQL server and I'm migrating some data over to MongoDB for a proof of concept project using Mongoose as the driver.  I want to add a DB ref to another collection.  A basic example of what I'm trying to do here:

Project Schema:

```
{
    projectNo: String,
    projectTitle: String
}
```

Document Schema:

```
{
    projectId: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'project'},
    projectNo: String,
    documentTitle: String
}
```

I want to add a new key to the Document schema that references the _id of the project collection.  If I was doing this in SQL Server I'd do this:

```
UPDATE document
SET projectId = project._id 
FROM project 
WHERE document.projectNo = project.projectNo
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thank you!

Kevin

Answer (score 0):

Ok I had to take off my SQL Server hat and think about it in JS terms.  For each project in project I want to update these collections with the project _id.  So I came up with this:

```
var proj = db.proj.find(); //load all the projects

proj.forEach(function(proj){ //loop through each one and update matching records in the collection
    db.forecast.update(
        {
            "projectNo" : proj.projectNo, 
            "$isolated" : true
        },{
            $set: { 
                projId : proj._id 
            }
        }, {
            "multi" : true 
    });
});
```

I'm sure there is another way to do this, I'm *very* open to suggestions.